# im a new learner and cant figure out why my code is not working

Tags: javascript

I have just recently got into coding and have chosen to learn JavaScript as my first language. I have written up code for a Rock, Paper, Scissors game but the wrong outputs come out when I run it? for example I would put my answer as scissors and the computer would choose rock and the game will come out as a tie.

```js
const getUserChoice = userInput => {
  if (userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors') {
    return userInput
  } else {
    return 'Error!'
  }
}

var getComputerChoice = () => {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  switch (randomNumber) {
    case 0:
      return 'rock'
      break;
    case 1:
      return 'paper'
      break;
    case 2:
      return 'scissors'
      break;
  }
};

const determineWinner = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
  if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
    return 'its a tie!';
  };
  if (userChoice === 'rock') {
    if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
      return 'computer won';
    } else {
      return 'user won';
    }
  }
  if (userChoice === 'paper') {
    if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
      return 'computer won';
    } else {
      return 'user won'
    }
  }
  if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
    if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
      return 'computer won';
    } else {
      return 'user won'
    }
  }
};


const playGame = () => {
  console.log(`player chose ${getUserChoice('scissors')}`);
  console.log(`computer chose ${getComputerChoice()}`);
  console.log(determineWinner(getUserChoice("scissors"), getComputerChoice()));
}
playGame();
```

Comment: Perfect opportunity to learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs). [Rubber Duck Debug](//rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code. Please try using the [debugging capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. How many times do you call `getComputerChoice()`? How many times is `Math.random` called in total?

Comment: Another hint:  look at your playGame function line by line. For each line ask yourself what is happening.  Are you storing function results in variables or just returning the values?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there are more issues, but here are some of them:

Each time you execute getComputerChoice you get a different value because a random value is picked inside:

```
  console.log(`player chose ${getUserChoice('scissors')}`);
  console.log(`computer chose ${getComputerChoice()}`);
  console.log(determineWinner(getUserChoice("scissors"), getComputerChoice()));
```

So you must instead call and store in variables:

```
  let playerChose = getUserChoice('scissors');
  let computerChose = getComputerChoice();
  let winner = determineWinner(playerChose, computerChose);
  console.log(`player chose ${playerChose}`);
  console.log(`computer chose ${computerChose}`);
  console.log(winner);
```

You can do it without variables, but be sure not invoking getComputerChoice several times.

Also userInput should be between parenthesis at:

```
const getUserChoice = (userInput) => {
```

Comment: You don't need parenthesis in arrow functions that has 1 parameter, so:
```js
const getUserChoice = userInput =>
```
Is correct

Comment: Should, but not must ;)
I think it improves readability...

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `getComputerChoice` you'll get a different value, you could **save** the values in a **variable** with the *const* keyword.

```js
const playGame = () => {
  // It would be nice if you request this to the user, with prompt
  const userChoice = getUserChoice('scissors');

  // Save the random value
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

  console.log(`player chose ${userChoice}`);
  console.log(`computer chose ${computerChoice}`);

  // This will work
  console.log(determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice));
}

playGame();
```

More on **prompt** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)

Comment: I see where i have gone wrong, got a lot of valuable information from this thank you!